# Add form.submit event to make sure that post occurs before form gets submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form. I want to add an event handler using jquery.

```
$("form").submit(function blah() {
   $.post('ping-me-please.php', params, function (response) {
       // only submit the form once this goes through!
   });

}
```

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    var form = $(this);

    if (!form.data('pinged')) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Cancel the submit
        $.post('ping-me-please.php', params, function (response) {
            // only submit the form once this goes through!

            // First we set the data, then we trigger the submit again.
            form.data('pinged', true).submit();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var postWasSent = false;
$("form").submit(function blah() {           
   if (!postWasSent)
   {
      $.post('ping-me-please.php', params, function (response) {
         postWasSent=True;
         $("form").submit();
      });
      return false;
   }

}
```

Comment: This requires multiple presses of the submit button, or synchronous post.